# Removing duplicate values based on attribute values in XSLTwithout hardcoding the attribute name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Below I have the piece of xml elements which are part of my xml document.
The need is to filter the elements based on the attributes value as well as the element value dynamically,which means without actually hardcoding the attributes value(Ex:@id or @name).
 Can you please help!!!

Sample Input:

```
<Products>
    <product id='1'>568</product>
    <product id='1'>598</product>
    <product name='8'>XYZ</product>
    <product name='8'>XYZ</product>
    <product category='9'>ABC</product>
</Products>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Products>
    <product id='1'>568</product>
    <product id='1'>598</product>
    <product name='8'>XYZ</product>
    <product category='9'>ABC</product>
</Products>
```

Comment: I don't  see an "example of xml elements with different attributes", there is only one attribute `rollno`. So you will need to explain in more details and/or with more input snippets how variable the input can be. And as you tag the question as xslt-2.0 and xslt-grouping, I suggest you add your attempt using XSLT 2.0's `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: Please find the updated peice of code

Comment: Your question is (still) not clear. Are you assuming each `product` will have only one attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to eliminate siblings which are duplicates you can use `deep-equal`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[some $p in preceding-sibling::product satisfies deep-equal(., $p)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum example stylesheet that generates your expected output from sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:acf="http://www.acme-dummy/xslt/function"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="student" group-by="acf:rolenoAndContent(.)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="acf:rolenoAndContent" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="prmStudent" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="concat($prmStudent/@rollno,' ',$prmStudent)"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If to realize not to hardcode @rollno, the following example will work as long as your input supplies same number of attributes for each student:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:acf="http://www.acme-dummy/xslt/function"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Class">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="student" group-by="acf:attsAndContent(.)">
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:function name="acf:attsAndContent" as="xs:string">
       <xsl:param name="prmStudent" as="element()"/>
       <xsl:variable name="attsAndValues" as="xs:string*">
           <xsl:for-each select="$prmStudent/@*">
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="concat(name(),':',.)"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:sequence select="concat(string-join($attsAndValues,' '),' ',$prmStudent)"/>
   </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>` can be shortened to `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` as inside the `for-each-group` the first item in each group is the context node. And `concat(string($prmStudent/@rollno),' ',string($prmStudent))` can be shortened to `concat($prmStudent/@rollno,' ',$prmStudent)` as the `concat` function will atomize its argument to a string anyway.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Thank you for your suggestion. I updated the stylesheet and tested them again.